# Uploading data from an excel to an already existing SharePoint custom list created within a SharePoint app

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I'm having a custom list which was created through visual studio in a SharePoint hosted app, now I want to upload data from an excel sheet to that existing list, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Sri it may be that you have a more complex situation than my solution can address, but please take a look at it on this related question to see if you find it helpful. :)
**Answer**: [Import/Copy/Paste Data from Excel into Existing SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224375/44163).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint Client Side Object Model for that. Here I've done that in my previous project. Please try it.

Assign proper values to variables. You can use simple console app for this.

**CODE:**

```
//assign variables with proper values
public static string siteUrl = "SharePoint Url";
public static string username = "username";
public static string password = "password";
public static string spListName = "list name";
public static string connString = string.Empty;
public static string filePath = string.Empty;


using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                try
                {
                    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
                    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, passWord);
                    Web Oweb = clientContext.Web;
                    clientContext.Load(Oweb);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    List spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(spListName);
                    clientContext.Load(spList);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    filePath = "C:\\Export\\" + spListName + ".xlsx";   //pass proper path and name of excel sheet 
                    try
            {
                string dirLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                List oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                ListItemCreationInformation listCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();

                if (filePath.EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + filePath + "'; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;'";
                }
                else if (filePath.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + filePath + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;'";
                }

                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        //Read Sheet
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        DataTable dtExcelSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                        con.Close();

                        string sheetName = "List Name"; //pass the excel sheet name
                        //Read the Header Row and value
                        cmd.CommandText = "select * from [" + sheetName + "$]";
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            System.Data.DataTable data = new DataTable();
                            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            da.Fill(data);

                            foreach (DataRow i in data.Rows)
                            {
                                ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(listCreationInformation);
                                if (listName != "Document Library")
                                {
                                    foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
                                    {
                                        if (column.ColumnName != "ID")
                                        {
                                            string columnValue = i[column.ColumnName].ToString();
                                            if (columnValue != "" || columnValue != string.Empty)
                                                oListItem[column.ColumnName] = columnValue;
                                            else
                                                oListItem[column.ColumnName] = null;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //Stops all event receivers while updating items in list
                                    using (var eventReceiverManager = new EventReceiverManager(true))
                                    {
                                        eventReceiverManager.StopEventReceiver();
                                        oListItem.Update();
                                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                                        eventReceiverManager.StartEventReceiver();
                                    }

                                    #region upload attachments
                                    string localfilePath = "C:\\Export\\" + i["ID"].ToString();
                                    bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(localfilePath);
                                    if(exists)
                                    {
                                        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(localfilePath);

                                        foreach(string s in filePaths)
                                        {
                                            using(FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(s))
                                            {
                                                var attInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
                                                attInfo.FileName = fs.Name;
                                                attInfo.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(s));

                                                Attachment att = oListItem.AttachmentFiles.Add(attInfo);
                                                context.Load(att);
                                                context.ExecuteQuery();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    #endregion
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SystemException ex)
            {

            }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    if (clientContext != null)
                        clientContext.Dispose();
                }
```