# Importing data from CSV to SharePoint Online list using Console Application (using Token)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365-developer

I am new to SharePoint Development, I am facing issue in importing the data to SPonline list. I am trying to import CSV data to a SharePoint Online custom list using client ID and Client Secret. I have written the below C# code to run in console application. But i am not getting the expected output(import data to list). Your help is appreciated!!!

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Sites"
             type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
  </configSections>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"> </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
  <Sites>
    <add key="site2"
         value="https://******.sharepoint.com"/>
  </Sites>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientId" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"/>
  </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Runtime;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {

                    var config = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Sites");
                    foreach (var key in config.Keys)
                    {

                         Uri siteUri = new Uri(config.GetValues(key as string)[0]);
                         //Get the realm for the URL
                         string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(siteUri);

                //Get the access token for the URL.  
                //   Requires this app to be registered with the tenant
                string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(
                    TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, 
                    siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;

                //Get client context with access token
                using(var clientContext = 
                    TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(
                        siteUri.ToString(),accessToken))
            {
                const string filePath = @"D:\import.csv";
                StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                string[] totalData = new string[System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Length];
                totalData = streamreader.ReadLine().Split('|');
                string strTitle;
                string strSurname = string.Empty;
                using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUri.ToString()))
                    {
                        Web currentWeb = clientContext.Web;
                        clientContext.Load(currentWeb);

                    while (!streamreader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        totalData = streamreader.ReadLine().Split('|');
                        strTitle = totalData[1];
                        strSurname = totalData[0];
                        if (totalData.Length > 2)
                        {
                            strSurname = totalData[2];
                        }
                        List spList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CSVList");
                        ListItemCreationInformation creationInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                        ListItem oListItem = spList.AddItem(creationInfo);
                        oListItem["Title"] = strTitle;
                        oListItem["Surname"] = strSurname;
                        oListItem.Update();
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    }
                }
            }


           }
                Console.WriteLine("...");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }




        }
    }
```

Comment: You can get some reference from here-http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161215/uploading-data-from-an-excel-to-an-already-existing-sharepoint-custom-list-creat/161221#161221

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the code and you can update accordingly to your logic.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Reflection;



namespace ConsoleApplication3
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {


                var configSites = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Sites");
                foreach (var key in configSites.Keys)
                {
                    Uri siteUri = new Uri(configSites.GetValues(key as string)[0]);
                    var siteUrls = configSites.GetValues(key as string);
                    var context = new ClientContext(siteUri.ToString());
                    if (siteUrls != null)
                    {
                        string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(siteUri);

                        string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;





                        using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(siteUri.ToString(), accessToken))
                        {

                            const string filePath = @"Your .CSV Path";
                            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                            {

                                string[] totalData = new string[System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Length];
                                string strName = string.Empty;
                                string strPartNumber = string.Empty;
                                string strSurName = string.Empty;
                                DateTime dtToday = DateTime.Now;


                                if (streamReader != null)
                                {
                                    Console.Write("while reading");

                                    totalData = streamReader.ReadLine().Split('|');

                                    if (totalData.Length > 1)
                                    {
                                        strName = totalData[1];
                                    }
                                    if (totalData.Length > 2)
                                    {
                                        strSurName = totalData[2];
                                    }

                                    if (totalData.Length > 5)
                                    {
                                        strPartNumber = totalData[5];
                                    }
                                    List spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Your Custom List Name");

                                    ListItemCreationInformation creationInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                                    ListItem oListItem = spList.AddItem(creationInfo);
                                    oListItem["Name"] = strName;
                                    oListItem["Title"] = strSurName;
                                    oListItem["Surname"] = strSurName;
                                    oListItem["BirthDate"] = dtToday;
                                    oListItem.Update();
                                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }


        }
    }
}
```